Kafka Consumers Fail to Start with RequestTimedOutError on MSK Cluster with Multiple Topics [Using AIOKafkaConsumer]
I'm using a Kafka MSK cluster with 3 nodes. I have a Kubernetes POD that spins up 14 different processes, and each process creates a Kafka consumer instance using AIOKafkaConsumer from the aiokafka library. All consumers share the same consumer group ID.
The issue arises when I attach 14 topics to this consumer group. The consumers fail to start, and I see the following error in the logs:
Error sending JoinGroupRequest_v2 to node 3 [[Error 7] RequestTimedOutError] -- marking coordinator dead
Marking the coordinator dead (node 3) for group masked_group.

However, when I reduce the number of topics attached to the consumer group from 14 to 4, the consumers start working fine.
Question:
What could be causing the RequestTimedOutError when multiple topics are attached?
Are there any Kafka configuration parameters or MSK settings I should consider adjusting to handle multiple topics more effectively with the same consumer group when using AIOKafkaConsumer?
Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
